# How to get webservice response in a protractor test

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate my application, I have a weird toggle button where it does not have button text in the html source instead it is returning a web service response, I'm new to web service concepts.

Toggle button source code:

[image]

```
<div class="assessment-config-switch assessment-switch">
<input id="fire_{"specialtyId":3,"activeTf":true,"specialtyName":"GI","quickCode":"GI","amaSpecialtyCode":null,"licenseKindId":null,"type":null,"itemId":3,"itemType":null,"itemName":"GI"}" class="showhideswitch-checkbox ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" type="checkbox" ng-click="assessmentConfigCtrl.saveToggleOption(assessmentConfigCtrl.fireOptions)" ng-model="assessmentConfigCtrl.fireOptions.configFlagTf">
<label class="showhideswitch-label" for="fire_{"specialtyId":3,"activeTf":true,"specialtyName":"GI","quickCode":"GI","amaSpecialtyCode":null,"licenseKindId":null,"type":null,"itemId":3,"itemType":null,"itemName":"GI"}">
<span class="showhideswitch-inner"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click the toggle button, I'm getting a web service response:

[image]
When i click on **Show** button the response would be as below

```
[
  {
    "configToggleMapId": 1086,
    "configId": 20,
    "organizationId": 76,
    "specialtyId": 3,
    "configFlagTf": true,
    "configValue": null,
    "config_Name": "Fire_Risk",
    "isUpdated": true
  }
]
```

When i click on **Hide** the response would be

```
[
  {
    "configToggleMapId": 1086,
    "configId": 20,
    "organizationId": 76,
    "specialtyId": 3,
    "configFlagTf": false,
    "configValue": null,
    "config_Name": "Fire_Risk",
    "isUpdated": true
  }
]
```

I need to get the value of **"configFlagTf"**, based on the return value I will do my operations.

Comment: Are you sure you need to go down into the service response - that does not sound right in the scope of e2e testing? Why don't just check which toggle is on - show or hide - would that be enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with alecxe. With Protractor you can only get information that users would have. As a user, you can see the state of the toggle button by the color.

You should be able to get the color of the button by writing something like myButton.getCssValue('color').

The problem is that the test will give false results if you change the color of your button.